# vim csupport compiler options

Tags: vim, gcc

How can I change compiler options (like adding -std=c99 or some library) when i use "\rc" command from csupport extension without GUI?

Answer (score 1):

If you switch to `\rm` to run `make` instead, you could place your `-std=c99` into your `Makefile`.

If you want to change the CFLAGS inside the plugin, you can set the `g:C_CFlags` variable; see the `:help csupport-custom` section for details.